British movie - Drug dealer close to retirement
I watched this movie around ten years ago. 
It was about a drug dealer in Britain, everyone speaks English with a British accent and British slang are used instead of American slang. 
This drug dealer is very close to retirement, but he is about to be given to the police by his boss, who is a informer. This drug dealer finds out and shoots his boss using a very unique pistol. 
Later, his dead boss's trusted henchman almost beats him to death but this drug dealer manages to convince the henchman that his boss is an informer. 
Another scene is, this drug dealer tries to murder an assassin by hiring a hitman of his own. I remember this hired hitman is listening to French lessons when he is traveling with the drug dealer. But the assassin shoots this hired hitman instead. 
The movie ends with this drug dealer making an exiting speech, something like, "you do not know my name do you?" Then I realized throughout this movie, this drug dealer is never named. But this drug dealer is shot by someone. 
Can anyone name this movie for me? It is very well made, but I can not remember its name or actors' names. 

I believe the movie you are referring to is "Layer Cake". Daniel Craig (of James Bond fame) played the unnamed protagonist that you mention. 
From  Wikipedia synopsis:

An unnamed man—appearing in the end credits only as XXXX—is a London
  underworld figure who has established himself in the cocaine business
  as one of the city's biggest suppliers, whilst presenting himself as a
  figure with legal business operations. Considering himself a
  businessman and a patient person, he leaves the darker aspects of the
  business to his henchman Morty, who had previously spent 10 years in
  prison for murder. Once he has earned enough to ensure his long-term
  financial security, XXXX plans to retire.
Approaching this point, his retirement plans go wrong when his
  powerful supplier Jimmy Price instructs XXXX to track down Charlie,
  the teenaged daughter of Price's associate, Eddie Temple, who has fled
  a rehabilitation centre along with her drug-addicted boyfriend. To
  track her down, XXXX enlists the help of two con men known as Cody and
  Tiptoes. To the frustration of XXXX, the boyfriend is found dead and
  Charlie has apparently been kidnapped, although no ransom has been
  demanded.
At the same time, Price instructs XXXX to organise the purchase and
  distribution of one million ecstasy tablets from a low-level gangster
  styling himself as "The Duke". XXXX does not know the pills had been
  stolen from a gang of Serbian war criminals based in the Netherlands,
  and who have been in hiding since the Yugoslav Wars and are now
  large-scale drug producers.
Meanwhile, XXXX encounters the Duke's nephew Sidney at a bar and
  becomes attracted to his disillusioned girlfriend Tammy. XXXX tries to
  broker the sale of the ecstasy pills to Liverpool gangsters Trevor and
  Shanks, but they refuse, informing him of the drugs' purloined nature
  and of the fact that the Serbs have sent an assassin, known as Dragan,
  to find the pills and kill those responsible for their theft. Because
  the Duke had mentioned XXXX's name to the Serbs beforehand, he, too,
  is now in danger. Members of the Duke's gang soon start turning up
  dead and the Duke himself goes missing.
XXXX arranges a tryst with Tammy, but before it can be consummated, he
  is kidnapped by henchmen of Eddie Temple (the father of Charlie).
  Temple informs him that Jimmy had lost £13 million in a failed
  investment in Africa and is now hoping to sell the pills to recoup his
  losses. He demands instead that XXXX sell the pills to him, and plays
  him a recording indicating that Jimmy has been a long-term informant
  for Scotland Yard and intends to betray XXXX to the police as soon as
  the deal is done, planning to gain clemency from the deal and also
  take away XXXX's wealth.
A furious XXXX shoots and kills Jimmy at his home, but does so with a
  gun that Gene, Jimmy's henchman, had used to commit a prior murder,
  putting both himself and Gene in danger. XXXX then discovers that his
  accountant, to whom Jimmy had referred him, has embezzled all of his
  money and disappeared. Gene and Morty, after being given evidence of
  Jimmy's snitching, acknowledge XXXX as the new acting boss and show
  him the corpse of the Duke, whom Gene had killed along with Duke's
  girlfriend, Slasher, when the latter threatened to alert the police
  about the pills.
To recoup something from the fiasco, XXXX tips the police off about
  the Duke's hideout, who then conduct a raid. XXXX is intentionally
  present during the raid to feign purchasing the pills from the Duke's
  crew, and Dragan, who has been following XXXX, watches the raid from
  afar as the police confiscate the drugs and as XXXX and Duke's crew
  escape. Meanwhile, XXXX has arranged for Cody and Tiptoes to con the
  raiding police unit out of the pills. XXXX delivers the severed head
  of the Duke to Dragan as a peace offering, who reports back to his
  Serbian boss that the police have seized the drugs. Cody and Tiptoes
  return the drugs to XXXX in exchange for a fee. However, when he
  attempts to sell them to Eddie Temple at the latter's bonded
  warehouse, Temple's henchmen rob his crew of the drugs at gunpoint. To
  end XXXX's faux assignment given by Jimmy, Temple reveals that he has
  put Charlie back into rehab.
To satisfy him, Temple then gives XXXX a "welcome to the layer cake"
  in the form of a membership to the Stoke Park Country Club of which he
  is a member and Jimmy was. Expecting betrayal, XXXX successfully
  arranges for Trevor, Shanks, and young Dizzy to steal the drugs back
  from Temple's men. The gang assembles for lunch at the Stoke Park
  Club, honoring XXXX their new boss. However, he demurs, stating his
  intention to stick to his planned retirement. When leaving the club
  with Tammy, mentally running through the names of his fellow murdered
  businessmen, he is shot by a heart-broken Sidney. XXXX collapses
  bleeding, and the film ends with him twitching on the club's front
  steps and thinking of his possible imminent death.

